# Firefox boxes Inkscape SVG elements

Tags: xml, firefox, svg, cross-browser

So, I realize that SVG support is not universal and may well be some time in coming and that I shouldn't expect perfection, but I'm getting some pretty unacceptable errors from FF in rendering what I consider to be a very simple SVG and I was wondering if someone had encountered a similar error before. 
[image]
In firefox

[image]
In Chrome

I can post all of the xml if needed, but it's pretty long and I feel it might be more confusing than useful. I believe this is a representative snippet, but I can add more if it would help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="15"
   height="15"
   id="svg3039">
  <metadata
     id="metadata3045">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs3043">
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient3962">
      <stop
         id="stop3970"
         style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0.79824561"
         offset="0" />
      <stop
         id="stop3966"
         style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0.56140351"
         offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient3942">
      <stop
         id="stop3944"
         style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1"
         offset="0" />
      <stop
         id="stop3946"
         style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0"
         offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <filter
       color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
       id="filter3781">
      <feGaussianBlur
         id="feGaussianBlur3783"
         stdDeviation="0.1674635" />
    </filter>
    <filter
       color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
       id="filter3785">
      <feGaussianBlur
         id="feGaussianBlur3787"
         stdDeviation="0.09938691" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <path
     d="m 10.839416,5.7481751 a 4.7846713,4.7846713 0 1 1 -9.5693426,0 4.7846713,4.7846713 0 1 1 9.5693426,0 z"
     id="path3055"
     style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#adadad;stroke-width:1.89999998;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;filter:url(#filter3781)" />
  <path
     d="m 8.5182482,10.313869 c 0,0 2.1590598,1.881089 2.9343068,2.540146 0.775247,0.659057 1.315147,1.217617 2.102189,1.116788 0.363811,-0.04661 0.706204,-0.3928 0.81022,-0.744526 0.132545,-0.448193 -0.0219,-1.007299 -0.350365,-1.357664 C 13.686132,11.518248 10.40146,8.5182482 10.40146,8.5182482 z"
     id="path3950"
     style="fill:#adadad;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#adadad;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:0.88627451;stroke-dasharray:none;filter:url(#filter3785)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Please do post the full xml

Comment: Here's a fiddle of that http://jsfiddle.net/gEbZE/, but I can't see that issue. Firefox does seem to clip away more content than the other browsers, but the blur is partially clipped in all of them.

Comment: @ErikDahlström The issue there is muted, but still visible. The issue is that there is a visible bounding box on the svg elements. The white lines slicing through the image there are the same issue.

Comment: @WebChemist Full XML posted.

Comment: I don't see any white lines in my Firefox nightly, what version do you see that in?

Comment: I'm using 21, does that mean this is an issue that should be fixed in the next release?

Comment: I don't see it either, don't know what to say... checked firefox 22 and 17

Comment: Issue is not in my beta channel FF22.

Comment: Bizarre, I upgraded and the problem seemed to go away, guess it was just for one release.

Comment: I still see the issue in FF24, googled this page trying to resolve the problem I experienced unexpectedly doing my own svg. http://jsfiddle.net/gEbZE/ shows the bad behavior.  Definitely related to the blur filter - perhaps failing to change the denominator when averaging the edge pixels?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try removing the `sodipodi` namespaced stuff, which sometimes causes issues, by saving as plain SVG from the "save as" feature.  Other hints on making web-safe svg are in [the inkscape manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Web-Inkscape.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly the error persists unchanged. Updating xml to reflect the change.

Comment: turns out to be a pretty localized problem, and this is a pretty useful answer for other things.

Comment: Does not address the problem.

Comment: Yeah, was a guess ... turned out to be a bug in FF it seems. But the reference to safe SVG is useful.